# Django: Add additional fields to UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-users

Can we add additional fields to UserCreationForm in django.

By default there are 5 fields in UserCreationForm:

1. username
2. email
3. first_name
4. last_name
5. password

If I want to add additional fields like age, gender then how can I add these in UserCreationForm.

I am new to django any reference or descriptive code will be appreciable.

Comment: # This Link [To Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049498/django-usercreationform-custom-fields) Will answer your question

Comment: This Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049498/django-usercreationform-custom-fields Will answer your question

Answer (score 4):

There are a few steps we need to follow,
**step 1 :** Inherit the UserCreationForm and add custom form fields to it, as per your case in **forms.py**

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    age = forms.IntegerField()
    gender = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'age', 'gender', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**step 2 :** Create a model as per your custom fields and create a OneToOneField relation with User in **models.py** file

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserData(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**step 3 :**  create a view that will invoke during POST method and will create a new user instance and will store the extra field data to the model which we created

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            age = form.cleaned_data.get('age')
            gender = form.cleaned_data.get('gender')
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            user_data = UserData.objects.create(user=user, age=age, gender=gender)
            user_data.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'base/signupform.html', {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Do This As Per The [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049498/django-usercreationform-custom-fields)

```py
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    # My Own Custom Fields
    username = forms.CharField(forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}), max_length=32, help_text='First name')
    last_name=forms.CharField(forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}), max_length=32, help_text='Last name')
    email=forms.EmailField(forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}), max_length=64, help_text='Enter a valid email address')
    password1=forms.CharField(forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2=forms.CharField(forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Password Again'}))

    # The Default Fields Of The UserCreation Form
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        # I've tried both of these 'fields' declaration, result is the same
        # fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
```

Comment: Thanks for response but the fields you have mentioned are already present in UserCreationForm, I am asking about some extra fields

Comment: @ShinChan the comment where i wrote "My Own Custom Fields" You Can Always Change the fields as per you requirenents.

Comment: Yes I agree with @AryanMishra. You can change the fields accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to store information related to User, you can use a OneToOneField to a model containing the fields for additional information.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    additional_field1 = models.SomeField()
    .....
```

Read the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) for the details on extending the user model.

Comment: where should I write above code, in models.py or in forms.py

Comment: In models.py @ShinChan